# How to get the text from first column of the table?

Tags: java, selendroid

I have tried with below coding to obtain the text from table.It works fine.But ,i want pick the data from first column alone.How can i grab the text from first column. .

```
WebElement tableContents = pubDriver.findElements(By.id("view_table"));

    List<WebElement> rows=tableContents.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
    for(int rnum=0;rnum<rows.size();rnum++)
    {
    List<WebElement> columns=rows.get(rnum).findElements(By.tagName("td"));

    for(int cnum=0;cnum<columns.size();cnum++)
    {
    System.out.println(columns.get(cnum).getText());
    }
    }
```

I have tried with below coding ,i didn't get the text from first column

```
columns.get(0).getText();
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do like this....

```
// Create a new instance of the html unit driver
// Notice that the remainder of the code relies on the interface, 
// not the implementation.
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

// And now use this to visit Google
driver.get("http://localhost:8081/TestXmlDisplay/tabletest.html");

WebElement tableContents = driver.findElement(By.tagName("table"));

List<WebElement> rows=tableContents.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
for(int rnum=0;rnum<rows.size();rnum++)
{
List<WebElement> columns=rows.get(rnum).findElements(By.tagName("td"));


System.out.println(columns.get(0).getText());

}
```

//  driver.quit();